# How to calculate new ability estimate after answered question in 1PL MLE computer adaptive tesing model?

Tags: php, r, statistics, mle

As you can probably tell from the question, I'm new to computer adaptive testing. I'm currently building a little computer adaptive test program using a 1P IRT curve.

I've been reading a lot of documentation regarding best methods but very few of them have examples for recalculating an iterative ability estimate after a new question has been answered. I do understand how to calculate ability at the end of a test however.

From my understanding the logic and math goes as follows:

Starting Ability: B0 = 0

Ability after problem 1: B1 = B0 + [summations and function evaluated for item 1 at ability B0]

Ability after problem 2: B2 = B1 + [summations and functions evaluated for items 1-2 at ability B1]

Ability after problem 3: B3 = B2 + [summations and functions evaluated for items 1-3 at ability B2]

Ability after problem 4: B4 = B3 + [summations and functions evaluated for items 1-4 at ability B3]

Ability after problem 5: B5 = B4 + [summations and functions evaluated for items 1-5 at ability B4]

I seem to be going wrong somewhere as my second ability estimate is different from all of the data sets I'm comparing to online.

Could anyone help break the calculation down past the i = 1 for me? Would be greatly appreciated!

I've attached an image of the modified Newton-Raphson formula I'm using to calculate ability after each question answer.

[image]

Here's an example of me trying to get things right on gsheets, as you can I get ability after item 1 correct at -0.8333. When I update the ability to -0.8333 and perform the calculations for item 2, I'm way off. Image four is the publication I'm using to test data against. As you can see, my ability estimate after item 2 is way off compared to what they're displaying.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the PHP tag relevant?

Comment: Writing it in php if that counts for anything.